# macOS Ventura Blenders uses between 300-771% of CPU

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am rendering a video. I set my quality to highest and speed to slowest. FFMPEG/RGB/ output container quicktime.

Even before render Blender gets super slow.

I noticed "building proxies" bottom of controls and quit that but in Activity Monitor I am seeing this wide range of CPU usage between 300% and high 700%

Is there a way to make this more responsive?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I am seeing this wide range of CPU usage between 300% and high 700%"  There is something slightly suspicious about these numbers...

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys it looks like Activity Monitor can report for each core or thread and combines the percentages, lol

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/movie_clip_editor/properties/proxy.html